# How to upload an image using WTF forms quick form

Tags: python, web, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am having trouble uploading an image amongst other fields. While the data for the other fields is present the image is not, hence the form is not being validated because of this.

here is the backend, see the image file field specifically, marked with # IMAGE

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, render_template, redirect, flash
import os
from flask import current_app as app
from src.models.products.product import Product
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField, FileField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileRequired
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename


dash_board_blueprint = Blueprint('dashboard', __name__, template_folder='templates')


class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[InputRequired()])
    category = StringField('Category', validators=[InputRequired()])
    sub_category = StringField('Sub Category', validators=[InputRequired()])
    size = StringField('Size', validators=[InputRequired()])
    variant = StringField('Variant', validators=[InputRequired()])
    price = StringField('Price', validators=[InputRequired()])
    enable_discount = BooleanField('Enable Discount')
    discount_price = StringField('Discount Price', validators=[InputRequired()])
    in_stock = BooleanField('In Stock')
    stock_amount = StringField('Stock Amount')
    text = StringField('Text')
    display_popular = BooleanField('Display Popular')
    image = FileField(validators=[FileRequired()]) # IMAGE
    submit = SubmitField("Add Product")

@dash_board_blueprint.route('/')
def dashboard():
    return render_template("dashboard/dashboard2.html", form=UploadForm())


@dash_board_blueprint.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():

    form = UploadForm()

    filename = form.image
    print("File Name:")
    print(filename)
```

Any sort of validation fails and the image contains None

Here is the HTML:

```
{% extends "dashboard_base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% macro render_form(form, action) %}
        {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
        <div id="Product" class="variant-block" style="display: block;">
            {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
            {% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
            {{ wtf.quick_form(form, action=action, extra_classes="size-options", button_map={'submit':'light'}) }}
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" style="background-color: #FAF6EA !important; height: 125px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <!-- *** Product Creation *** -->
            <div style="background-color: #FAF6EA !important; " class=" container col-sm-4 mt-3 py-3 pl-5">
                {{ render_form(form, url_for('dashboard.upload')) }}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you setting `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form?

[Per the Flask-WTF docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html):

> Remember to set the enctype of the HTML form to multipart/form-data,
>   otherwise request.files will be empty.

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
</form>
```

Your example leads me to believe you are using the Flask-Bootstrap extension. If you are, `enctype` should automatically be set to `"multipart/form-data"` if you don't explicitly set it otherwise and `FileField` is present in your form ([per the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/forms.html). However, I wonder if how you're declaring your form is causing this not to not be the case. You might want to try explicitly setting the `enctype` in your form statement.

Comment: It was my case. Don't know why but I had to include the enctype in my template to make it work : {{ wtf.quick_form(form,enctype="multipart/form-data") }}. Thanks!